# Can't run app in the simulator iOS 8 Xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8

I receive the following error when trying to launch ios app in the iOS8 simulator:

> 9/12/14 1:32:02.953 PM
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[5355]: Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7fc63f406240
>   {Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load
>   Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/myexec/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B21BB739-E031-41DA-9FF1-11DA4B4EB7B9/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.zJ0bBq/extracted/Myapp.app/Frameworks/LiveSDK.framework}

I can't understand what is wrong. It runs with no problem on iOS 7.1 simulator.

Comment: Is your app working well in device?

Comment: No, the error there is something like "Package inspection check failed."

Comment: Restarting simulator solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the exact same problem. Was using shareKit. But I did not need that LiveSDK support. Thus, after hours of trying to find a solution, I simply put "livesdk" in search box (search in workspace) and removed every entry of it. Also - removed LiveSDK files from Sharekit.  And problem disappeared. (Hopefully I will never need to add LiveSDK support).

Comment: Even after removing ShareKit I was still seeing this issue. What finally fixed it for me was holding down the Option key and then choosing Product > Clean Build Folder

Comment: @dirkoneill - this was the only answer that worked for me as well. Thanks. You should submit it as an answer instead of comment so we can upvote it.

Answer (score 28):

Even after removing ShareKit I was still seeing this issue. What finally fixed it for me was holding down the Option key and then choosing Product > Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 12):

Launch the iphone simulator then go to simulator->reset contents and settings.
Then,quit all the application and restart your mac.

Answer (score 6):

Cleaning the build folder resolved the issue for me. I hope it helps someone!

(While holding down the Alt-key: Product > Clean build folder)

Answer (score 2):

People who do not want to remove ShareKit or LiveSDK, here is another workaround I did. I could copy(link) the Info.plist for LiveSDK.framework to resolve this issue. What all I did was:

```
ln -s Pods/ShareKit/Frameworks/LiveSDK.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Info.plist Pods/ShareKit/Frameworks/LiveSDK.framework/
```

by the way, I installed ShareKit by CocoaPods.

Comment: It was in compile error logs that the Info.plist was missing in the right directory. I think this is just a simple bug of Sharekit pods related to configuration or setup of the Pods. I don't know well about Pods and I didn't want to spend time to figure out to fix it. Hopefully it will be gone at later versions

Comment: Yeah, almost ripped out ShareKit over this. Again, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I have just went through this issue, and figured out that this issue is related to memory usage.

**To get rid of this : try following ways:** 
 - Clean your project

- Restart Simulator and/or Xcode
- Check your code, if there are some lines of code utilising high memory.
- Or, your systems start-up memory is almost full: try free up some space.
- Lastly, if nothing works restart your system. (This worked for me).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

For me, I quit the simulator and then built the code again and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting simulator worked for me,

`Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... > Reset`